# Keras fit_generator() & Input array should have the same as target samples

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, keras

So far I'm trying to implement the fit-generator for sentiment analysis as I only have a small PGU and big dataset. But I keep getting this error

```
Using Theano backend.
Can not use cuDNN on context None: cannot compile with cuDNN. We got this error:
b'In file included from C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v8.0\\include/driver_types.h:53:0,\r\n                 from C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v8.0\\include/cudnn.h:63,\r\n                 from C:\\Users\\Def\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\try_flags_p2iwer2o.c:4:\r\nC:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v8.0\\include/host_defines.h:84:0: warning: "__cdecl" redefined\r\n #define __cdecl\r\n ^\r\n<built-in>: note: this is the location of the previous definition\r\nd000029.o:(.idata$5+0x0): multiple definition of `__imp___C_specific_handler\'\r\nd000026.o:(.idata$5+0x0): first defined here\r\nC:/Users/Def/Anaconda3/envs/Final/Library/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o: In function `__tmainCRTStartup\':\r\nC:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:285: undefined reference to `_set_invalid_parameter_handler\'\r\ncollect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status\r\n'
Mapped name None to device cuda: GeForce GTX 960M (0000:01:00.0)
Epoch 1/10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Def/PycharmProjects/KerasUkExpenditure/TweetParsing.py", line 136, in <module>
    epochs=10)
  File "C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\envs\Final\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 88, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\envs\Final\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 1097, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\envs\Final\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 88, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\envs\Final\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1876, in fit_generator
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\envs\Final\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1614, in train_on_batch
    check_batch_axis=True)
  File "C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\envs\Final\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1307, in _standardize_user_data
    _check_array_lengths(x, y, sample_weights)
  File "C:\Users\Def\Anaconda3\envs\Final\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 229, in _check_array_lengths
    'and ' + str(list(set_y)[0]) + ' target samples.')
ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1000 input samples and 1 target samples.
```

I have a matrix that is 1000 elements long since I only have a maximum corpus of 1000 words which is specified in the Tokenizer().

I then have the sentiment which is either a 0 for negative or a 1 for positive.

My question is why do I receive the error? I have tried to use the transform on both the data and labels and I still receive the same error. here is my code.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re

"""
the amount of samples out to the 1 million to use, my 960m 2GB can only handle
about 30,000ish at the moment depending on a number of neurons in the
deep layer and a number of layers.
"""
maxSamples = 3000

#Load the CSV and get the correct columns
data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Def\\Desktop\\Sentiment Analysis Dataset1.csv")
dx = pd.DataFrame()
dy = pd.DataFrame()
dy[['Sentiment']] = data[['Sentiment']]
dx[['SentimentText']] = data[['SentimentText']]

dataY = dy.iloc[0:maxSamples]
dataX = dx.iloc[0:maxSamples]

testY = dy.iloc[maxSamples: maxSamples + 1000]
testX = dx.iloc[maxSamples: maxSamples + 1000]


"""
here I filter the data and clean it up by removing @ tags, hyperlinks and
also any characters that are not alpha-numeric.
"""
def removeTagsAndLinks(dataframe):
    for x in dataframe.iterrows():
        #Removes Hyperlinks
        x[1].values[0] = re.sub("(http|ftp|https)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?", "", str(x[1].values[0]))
        #Removes @ tags
        x[1].values[0] = re.sub("@\\w+", '', str(x[1].values[0]))
        #keeps only alpha-numeric chars
        x[1].values[0] = re.sub("\W+", ' ', str(x[1].values[0]))
    return dataframe

xData = removeTagsAndLinks(dataX)
xTest = removeTagsAndLinks(testX)

"""
This loop looks for any Tweets with characters shorter than 2 and once found write the
index of that Tweet to an array so I can remove from the Dataframe of sentiment and the
list of Tweets later
"""
indexOfBlankStrings = []
for index, string in enumerate(xData):
    if len(string) < 2:
        indexOfBlankStrings.append(index)

for row in indexOfBlankStrings:
    dataY.drop(row, axis=0, inplace=True)

"""
This makes a BOW model out of all the tweets then creates a
vector for each of the tweets containing all the words from
the BOW model, each vector is the same size becuase the
network expects it
"""
def vectorise(tokenizer, list):
    return tokenizer.fit_on_texts(list)

#Make BOW model and vectorise it
t = Tokenizer(lower=False, num_words=1000)
t.fit_on_texts(dataX.iloc[:,0].tolist())
t.fit_on_texts(dataX.iloc[:,0].tolist())

"""
Here im experimenting with multiple layers of the total
amount of words in the syllabus divided by ^2 - This
has given me quite accurate results compared to random guess's
of amount of neron's.
"""
l1 = int(xData.shape[0] / 4) #To big for my GPU
l2 = int(xData.shape[0] / 8) #To big for my GPU
l3 = int(xData.shape[0] / 16)
l4 = int(xData.shape[0] / 32)
l5 = int(xData.shape[0] / 64)
l6 = int(xData.shape[0] / 128)


#Make the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(l1, input_dim=xData.shape[1]))
model.add(Dropout(0.15))
model.add(Dense(l2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(l3))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(l4))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))

#Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='RMSProp', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

"""
This here will use multiple batches to train the model.
    startIndex:
        This is the starting index of the array for which you want to
        start training the network from.
    dataRange:
        The number of elements use to train the network in each batch so
        since dataRange = 1000 this mean it goes from
        startIndex...dataRange OR 0...1000
    amountOfEpochs:
        This is kinda self explanitory, the more Epochs the more it
        is supposed to learn AKA updates the optimisation algo numbers
"""
amountOfEpochs = 1
dataRange = 1000
startIndex = 0

def generator(tokenizer, data, labels, totalSize=maxSamples, startIndex=0):
    l = labels.as_matrix()
    while True:
        for i in range(startIndex, totalSize):
            batch_features = tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(xData.iloc[i])
            batch_labels = l[i]
            yield batch_features, batch_labels

derp = generator(t, data=xData, labels=dataY)
##This runs the model for batch AKA load a little them process then load a little more
for amountOfData in range(1000, maxSamples, 1000):
    #(loss, acc) = model.train_on_batch(x=dim[startIndex:amountOfData], y=np.asarray(dataY.iloc[startIndex:amountOfData]))
    history = model.fit_generator(generator=generator(tokenizer=t,
                                            data=xData,
                                            labels=dataY),
                                            steps_per_epoch=1,
                                            epochs=10)
```

Thanks

Comment: The problem is you have 1000 samples in you X input matrix and 1 in your output Y matrix

Comment: But the 1 in the Y matrix is the sentiment. it should only be 1 or 0 for each Tweet

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that the number of samples in your input array, do not equal the number of samples in your target array. This means the number of rows in you matrices do not match. The problems stems from your generator function. You index the data as

```
batch_labels = l[i]
```

which is only returning one sample (row of matrix). When instead it should be something like...

```
batch_labels = l[i:i+1000]
```

However there are other problems with your use of the fit_generator. You should not be using this within a loop. I don't see how it is benefiting the program, and calling the fit_generator in a loop defeats the purpose of using a generator. The function you would use to train an an individual batch of data would be

```
train_on_batch()
```

as seen in the [docs](https://keras.io/models/sequential/)